# Divs move around when i zoom in/out

Tags: html, zooming, out

My webpage layout is changing when i zoom in and out on google chrome!

Here is the link to my website:
http://party.mccrossings.net

I did already check other posts which did not help me out!

Comment: Please help insted of dowvotng i would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

To keep your `content` div centered, add the following properties:

```
#content {
    width: 800ppx;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)